# Parse array of event objects and match sets of statuses with correct start stop dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, algorithm

```
# statusstart        statusend          statusname
2020-08-25 07:00:24 2020-08-25 07:00:24 MICRO STOP  
2020-08-25 07:00:24 2020-08-25 07:02:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:02:24 2020-08-25 07:04:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:04:24 2020-08-25 07:06:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:06:24 2020-08-25 07:08:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:08:24 2020-08-25 07:10:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:10:24 2020-08-25 07:12:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:12:24 2020-08-25 07:15:24 UNKNOWN STATUS
2020-08-25 07:15:24 2020-08-25 07:16:10 PRODUCTION
2020-08-25 07:16:10 2020-08-25 07:17:00 PRODUCTION
2020-08-25 07:17:00 2020-08-25 07:18:00 MICRO STOP  
2020-08-25 07:18:00 2020-08-25 07:19:00 UNKNOWN STATUS
```

I want to output an array like this:

```
[['MICRO STOP', 2020-08-25 07:00:24, 2020-08-25 07:00:24],
['UNKNOWN STATUS', 2020-08-25 07:00:24, 2020-08-25 07:15:24],
['PRODUCTION', '2020-08-25 07:15:24', '2020-08-25 07:17:00'],
['MICRO STOP', '2020-08-25 07:17:00', '2020-08-25 07:18:00']
['UNKNOWN STATUS', '2020-08-25 07:18:00', '2020-08-25 07:19:00']
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
let status = '';
let statusStart: Date;
let statusEnd: Date;

let data = new Array<any>();

this.evolutionAnalysis.forEach((e, idx) => {
    if(status === '') {
        status = e.statusname;
        statusStart = new Date(e.statusstart);
    }

    if (e.statusname !== status) {
        
        statusEnd = new Date(this.evolutionAnalysis[idx - 1].statusend);
        data.push([
            this.operatorsAnalysis.find(o => o.operatorid == e.operatorid).operatorname, 
            status,
            statusStart,
            statusEnd
        ]);

        status = e.statusname;
    } 
});
```

How do I determine statusStart, after I know statusEnd

Comment: Other than missing code to output the last sequence (after the `forEach`), what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Nick, I don't know how to determine startStatus

Comment: @MrSmith42 How do I determine statusStart, after I know statusEnd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the predecessor, if it has the same name and update the end time.

```js
const
    data = [{ statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:00:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:00:24', statusname: 'MICRO STOP' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:00:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:02:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:02:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:04:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:04:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:06:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:06:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:08:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:08:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:10:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:10:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:12:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:12:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:15:24', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:15:24', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:16:10', statusname: 'PRODUCTION' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:16:10', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:17:00', statusname: 'PRODUCTION' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:17:00', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:18:00', statusname: 'MICRO STOP' }, { statusstart: '2020-08-25 07:18:00', statusend: '2020-08-25 07:19:00', statusname: 'UNKNOWN STATUS' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { statusstart, statusend, statusname }, i, a) => {
        if (a[i - 1]?.statusname === statusname) {
            r[r.length - 1][2] = statusend;
        } else {
            r.push([statusname, statusstart, statusend]);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group it by consecutive `statusname` and map through that group, get the `statusstart` of the first element of the group and `statusend` of the last one

```js
const evolutionAnalysis = [
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:00:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:00:24", statusname:"MICRO STOP" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:00:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:02:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:02:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:04:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:04:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:06:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:06:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:08:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:08:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:10:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:10:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:12:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:12:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:15:24", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:15:24", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:16:10", statusname:"PRODUCTION" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:16:10", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:17:00", statusname:"PRODUCTION" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:17:00", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:18:00", statusname:"MICRO STOP" },
  { statusstart: "2020-08-25 07:18:00", statusend: "2020-08-25 07:19:00", statusname:"UNKNOWN STATUS" },
]

const groupedEvolutionAnalysis = []

for (let i = 0; i < evolutionAnalysis.length; i++) {
  const group = [evolutionAnalysis[i]]
  while (
    evolutionAnalysis[i + 1] &&
    evolutionAnalysis[i + 1].statusname === evolutionAnalysis[i].statusname
  ) {
    group.push(evolutionAnalysis[i + 1])
    i++
  }
  groupedEvolutionAnalysis.push(group)
}

const res = groupedEvolutionAnalysis.map(group => [
  group[0].statusname,
  group[0].statusstart,
  group[group.length - 1].statusend
])

console.log(res)
```